# When I use 'auto' in the first loop it works fine, but with 'int' it gives an error, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14

As you can see, my code works fine, but I had a doubt about use of `auto` and `int` in the first loop while accessing a `vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> a{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    //why don't work when i use int in the first loop,and why it work when i use auto  
    for(auto n:a)
    {
        for(int b:n)
        {
           cout<<b<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
 }
```

Comment: auto from vector<int> is replaced by int but the auto from vector<vector<int>> cat be replaced with vector<int>

Comment: For the same reason that `int x = a[0];` is an error.

Answer (score 5):

because in the first loop (the outer one), `n` type is an `std::vector<int>` not an `int`.

Note that `a` is a vector of vectors, hence its elements are vectors, not integers. And of course, the elements of each element of its elements are integers.

The range-based loop can be written explicitly as

```
for(vector<int> n:a)
```

Or even better

```
for(vector<int>& n:a)
```

to avoid copying

Or even more better

```
for(const vector<int>& n:a)//equivalent to for(const auto & n:a)
```

because you don't make a change to it

Comment: For similar reasons the `auto` version is better written as `for (const auto& n : a)`